# When I use localhost connect, if I use the IP it doesn't connect

Tags: c#, grpc

I run the server and the client in the same computer, for testing. If in the client I use the address localhost it works, but if I use the IP of the computer "192.16.1.33" it fails. The error message is this:

```
    D0725 20:25:53.870862 Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension gRPC native library loaded successfully.
D0725 20:25:53.872652 0 T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy_registry.cc:39: registering LB policy factory for "grpclb"
D0725 20:25:53.872779 0 T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy_registry.cc:39: registering LB policy factory for "cds_experimental"
D0725 20:25:53.872871 0 T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy_registry.cc:39: registering LB policy factory for "eds_experimental"
D0725 20:25:53.872962 0 T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy_registry.cc:39: registering LB policy factory for "lrs_experimental"
D0725 20:25:53.873053 0 T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy_registry.cc:39: registering LB policy factory for "priority_experimental"
D0725 20:25:53.873118 0 T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy_registry.cc:39: registering LB policy factory for "weighted_target_experimental"
D0725 20:25:53.873181 0 T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy_registry.cc:39: registering LB policy factory for "xds_routing_experimental"
D0725 20:25:53.873249 0 T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy_registry.cc:39: registering LB policy factory for "pick_first"
D0725 20:25:53.873311 0 T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy_registry.cc:39: registering LB policy factory for "round_robin"
D0725 20:25:53.873377 0 T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\c_ares\dns_resolver_ares.cc:504: Using ares dns resolver
I0725 20:25:55.903532 0 T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\subchannel.cc:1033: Connect failed: {"created":"@1595701555.902000000","description":"OS Error","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\iomgr\tcp_client_windows.cc","file_line":105,"os_error":"Unable to retrieve error string","syscall":"ConnectEx","wsa_error":10061}
I0725 20:25:55.904211 0 T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\subchannel.cc:970: Subchannel 0000016821801D70: Retry immediately
I0725 20:25:55.904411 0 T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\subchannel.cc:997: Failed to connect to channel, retryin
```

It seems that the channel is created, because it is the subchannel 0000016821801D70, but for some reason can't get the response from the server.

The code of the server is this:

const int miPort = 5001;

```
            var cacert = File.ReadAllText("Keys/ca.crt");
            var cert = File.ReadAllText("Keys/server.crt");
            var key = File.ReadAllText("Keys/server.key");

            var keypair = new KeyCertificatePair(cert, key);
            var sslCreds = new SslServerCredentials(new List<KeyCertificatePair>
                                {
                                    keypair
                                }, cacert, false);

            Server server = new Server()
            {
                Services = { Gestor.BindService(new GestorAplicacionesService()) },
                //Ports = { new ServerPort("0.0.0.0", miPort, sslCreds) },
                Ports = { new ServerPort("localhost", miPort, sslCreds) },
            };
            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Started server on port " + miPort);
            server.ShutdownTask.Wait();
```

The code of my client is this:

```
var miCaCertificate = File.ReadAllText("Keys/ca.crt");
                var miClientCertificate = File.ReadAllText("Keys/client.crt");
                var miClientPrivateKey = File.ReadAllText("Keys/client.key");

            var keypair = new KeyCertificatePair(_clientCertificate, _clientPrivateKey);
            var sslCreds = new SslCredentials(_caCertificate, keypair);

            var channel = new Channel(_serviceAddress, _port, sslCreds);
            var client = new Gestor.GestorClient(channel);

            await client.MiSaludoAsync();
```

The certificates works, because with localhost it works, but this is the script that I use to create a self signed certificates with OpenSSL:

```
# Generate valid CA
openssl genrsa -passout pass:1234 -des3 -out ca.key 4096
openssl req -passin pass:1234 -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -subj  "/C=SP/ST=Spain/L=Valdepenias/O=Test/OU=Test/CN=Root CA"

# Generate valid Server Key/Cert
openssl genrsa -passout pass:1234 -des3 -out server.key 4096
openssl req -passin pass:1234 -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj  "/C=SP/ST=Spain/L=Valdepenias/O=Test/OU=Server/CN=localhost"
openssl x509 -req -passin pass:1234 -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out server.crt

# Remove passphrase from the Server Key
openssl rsa -passin pass:1234 -in server.key -out server.key

# Generate valid Client Key/Cert
openssl genrsa -passout pass:1234 -des3 -out client.key 4096
openssl req -passin pass:1234 -new -key client.key -out client.csr -subj  "/C=SP/ST=Spain/L=Valdepenias/O=Test/OU=Client/CN=localhost"
openssl x509 -passin pass:1234 -req -days 365 -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out client.crt

# Remove passphrase from Client Key
openssl rsa -passin pass:1234 -in client.key -out client.key




pause
```

I have tried with 2 servers certificates. One I use as common name "localhost", this works when I run the client in the same computer, but it doesn't work when in the client I use the IP.

Later I have tried another server certificate, with the IP as common name, but I can't still connect to the server.

What I have read is that in the certificate server

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/23616#issuecomment-667112513

Comment: Are you referencing any files?  I think what is happening is the server program is exiting due to an exception and not returning a response.  The exception is occurring due to the server not being able to access a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a certificate for an IP is a bit different than creating a certificate for a name. For a certificate you can add an alternative name (this is how you create wildcard or multi-domain certificates) or a list of IP addresses.

Check the configuration of OpenSSL if the `[alt_names]` is correct. See https://medium.com/@antelle/how-to-generate-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-an-ip-address-f0dd8dddf754 for a bit more information

To make sure that your certificate is for a domain name or an ip address, use the command `openssl x509 -in client.crt -text -noout`, in the output of this command you will see something as follow:

```
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                IP Address:127.0.0.1
```

if it starts with 'DNS:' instead of 'IP Address', then you need to update the creation of your certificate.

Comment: I will check the link. But this makes me wondering, I guess localhost can't be use as common name if i want to access from another computer. So, I have tried the name of my computer, I am using windows 10 in my server, and I have tried the name of computer in windows (it is not in a domain). The name is Server01. But Have created a certificate with common name Server01 but it doesn't work too.

Comment: This is something that you solve with the `[alt_names]`, here you can enter multiple dns and ip addresses, in your case the ip 127.0.0.1, the name 'localhost' and your computer name. See https://security.stackexchange.com/q/74345 for how you can add these alternative names from the command line.

Comment: Also, something that I forgot to mention, you must make sure that your certificate is installed in the certificate store where you run your program, try the `Personal` or `Trusted Root Certification`. Only certificates signed with a certificate that is present here will be allowed

Comment: I used SAN, and when I run my server, if I try to connect with a browser, I get a messsage that tells it is not a private connection. If I stop the server and try to connect with the browser, I get a message that says that the address is not found. So I think the server is correct. However, if I try to connect with the gRPC client, i get the same error.